# Eclipse - WindowBuilder - Unhandled event loop exception

Tags: linux, swt, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-indigo

All eclipses' windowbuilder (either swing or gwt) I have behave strange... Adding each new component or widget makes all IDE get lost its focus (becomes disabled); I've notices I am facing an exception in my "*eclipse 3.7 indigo j2ee x64 for linux*" called :

> Unhandled event loop exception

...each time I add a widget in my eclipse (here is the detailed ):

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: XPCOM error -2147467259
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.error(Mozilla.java:2502)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initXULRunner(Mozilla.java:2464)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Mozilla.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Browser.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.css.dialogs.style.RulePreviewControl.<init>(RulePreviewControl.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.css.editors.multi.StylesEditComposite.createRuleGroup(StylesEditComposite.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.css.editors.multi.StylesEditComposite.createContents(StylesEditComposite.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.css.editors.multi.StylesEditComposite.<init>(StylesEditComposite.java:101)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.model.property.css.StylesEditComposite.<init>(StylesEditComposite.java:74)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.model.property.css.StylesEditDialog.createAreaContents(StylesEditDialog.java:88)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.model.property.css.StylesEditDialog.createDialogArea(StylesEditDialog.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createContents(Dialog.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.model.widgets.SelectionActionsSupport$CssEditAction.run(SelectionActionsSupport.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.actions.DesignPageAction.run(DesignPageAction.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$6.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3588)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3209)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

and session data :

```
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.7.0_71
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product --launcher.GTK_version 2 org.eclipse.platform
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product --launcher.GTK_version 2 org.eclipse.platform
```

...only IDE window resizing getting focus back,as a result, I can hardly use eclipse IDE ;
That occur in each my eclipse where I am trying to use GUI IDE tools :

- eclipse 3.7 indigo j2ee x64 for linux
- eclipse 3.7 indigo j2se x64 for linux
- eclipse 4.3 kepler j2ee x64 for linux

So my question is... what causes the error and how to fix it?

Thanks